# Attempt to initialize the CRT more than once

Tags: visual-c++

I am using VS2008 to port code from VC6.  When I ran the new build app, I get this error "R6031 Attemp to initialize the CRT more than once.  This indicates a bug in your application".

There are a total of 21 dlls that are involve in the build this one app.  Some DLL has .c files in them and explicitly calls _CRT_INIT() in DllMain.  code below:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
 switch( dwReason) 
 {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

      if(!_CRT_INIT( hModule, dwReason, lpReserved))
    return FALSE;

   break;
 }

 return TRUE;
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem.  Do I need to comment out the call to _CRT_INIT()?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should not need to call `_CRT_INIT()` explicitly. It's probably being called by one or another `DLLMain`.

See [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94248) for details.

**Edit**

I think you have misread MSDN:

> When building a DLL which uses any of
>   the C Run-time libraries, in order to
>   ensure that the CRT is properly
>   initialized, either
>
> 1. the initialization function must be named DllMain() and the entry point
>      must be specified with the linker
>      option -entry:_DllMainCRTStartup@12 -
>      or -

You *have* named the init function `DllMain()`, so `_CRT_INIT()` *is* being called automatically. I think.

Why not simply comment out that line and see what happens?

Comment: MSDN says that the DLL's entry point must explicitly call CRT_INIT() on process attach and process detach

Comment: In 15 years of Win32 programming I have never once needed to explicitly initialize the CRT in DllMain. I agree with egrunin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173740%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is specific to mixed-mode assemblies.  Have you enabled the CLR during the port by mistake?  You should not see this during a simple port from VC6 to a later Visual C++ revision.

> This diagnostic indicates that MSIL
>   instructions were executing during
>   loader lock. For more information, see
>   Initialization of Mixed Assemblies.

You can check the project setting by right-clicking the project in Solution Explorer, then under Properties look at Configuration Properties -> General -> Common Language Runtime Support

Comment: No, I did not enable /clr switch.  There are lots of .c files and they can not be compiled using /clr switch

Comment: I suggest running this in the debugger to see if the output window and callstack tells you more about what was going on when the error occurs.